# Is it possible to acquire currently applied cursor style from browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to acquire the actual current cursor style regardless of various overlays, overlaps, pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes?

Experiment sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-shaw-3c2zl?file=/src/styles.css

```js
el.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(ev.target).cursor
  console.log(ev.target, style)
})
```

```
div.Two:hover { // reports 'grab' on click
  cursor: grab;
}


div.Two::before {
  cursor: crosshair; // reports 'auto' on click
}
```

*This Q/A doesn't address this specifically: [how to use javascript get current cursor style from browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38762367/how-to-use-javascript-get-current-cursor-style-from-browser)*

Comment: Pseudos aren't part of the DOM, so this isn't possible.

Comment: I was trying it also by detecting whether user interacts with element or its pseudo-element and then reading the `getComputedStyle(ev.target, '::before')`, but it's not possible to tell: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61876248/985454